# Naming convention for fluent methods in C#?

Tags: c#, naming, fluent

## Main question

Is there a naming convention for fluent C# methods?  I'd like readers to know that a method follows the fluent design pattern when seeing the method's name.

## Background

I'm about to write a class type that uses a lot of fluent methods to build on a static factory-style constructor.  For example,

```
Person bob = Person.New()
                   .Name("Bob")
                   .Age(30)
                   .Location("USA")
                   .MakeAwesome()
                   .PutACatOnHisHeadJustToScrewWithHim()
                   .MakeIntoStackOverflowExample();
```

I understand that optional arguments would be one approach to this process.  For example, it could be

```
Person bob = Person.New(
                         name : "Bob"
                       , age : 30
                       , location : "USA"
                       , isAwesome : true
                       , hasACatOnHisHeadJustToScrewWithHim : true
                       , isAStackOverflowExample : true
                   );
```

, but I'd prefer fluent methods because the named-argument approach is more limited to single method calls, making it less practical to add a cat to Bob's head later on after construction.

Since the project hasn't employed fluent methods yet, I'd like to name them in a way that makes their fluent nature obvious.  I suppose that `fluent_AssertName` could work in place of `Name()`, but that seems cumbersome.  Currently I'm thinking `F_Name()`.

## Updates

While the above example is for a constructor, I'd like to use this fluent approach throughout the program's operation.  Also, the fluent approach has the advantage of being ordered and allowing for redundancies.

```
Number x = Number.New(0)
                 .Add(1)
                 .Multiply(2)
                 .Subtract(1)
                 .Multiply(2)
                 ;
// ...other code that uses x...
x.Add(5)
 .Multiply(10);
```

The fluent approach seems to be the best in my particular use case.  I'm just looking for an obvious naming convention to reflect this design pattern.

Comment: As an option you can put your fluent methods in a builder and then use property names of original class as method names of builder class. for example `var p = PersonBuilder.New().Name("Bob").Age(30).Location("USA").Get();`

Comment: Fluent methods are often used with immutable classes, are you going down that route? Also I would avoid prefixing methods with `F_` or `Fluent...`. Instead, fluent methods tend to be actions or verbs such as `SetValue`, `Save` and `ToList`. Either way, this question (while being a good question!) is off topic for SO due to it being opinion based.

Comment: @DavidG: In this case it's a mutable class, though the project also involves immutable classes so those may be relevant soon.  Thanks for the topic-appropriateness note - would there be a more appropriate StackExchange site for asking questions about programming conventions?

Comment: I'm not really sure there are any places in the SO network (they renamed the entire company to Stackoverflow recently!) due to the opinion based nature.[programmers.se] might be but I'm really not sure if they would allow it.

Comment: @DavidG: Definitely looks like other questions on naming conventions had gone to Programmers.  Would there be an appropriate way to proceed here, like some feature to move this question?

Comment: I guess you could flag to migrate it, but I'd probably leave it here and go open another one over there.

Comment: And don't come back and shout at me if P.SE close it too :)

Comment: @DavidG Questions on naming are primarily opinion-based and will be closed at Programmers, same as here: many of the questions migrated to there from here suffered that fate. Furthermore, please do not recommend another SE site unless you are familiar with what is on-topic there. Please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Comment: Also, please do not encourage **[cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)**.

Comment: Admittedly I'm somewhat confused about how asking about whether or not there's a well-known naming convention is primarily opinion based.  I can see how different people could perceive different conventions to be more common, though overall the existence or non-existence of a common convention strikes me as a relatively factual issue.

Comment: I would recommend you do this kind of thing: [code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gvrq6i). It's a true fluent builder class. This avoids the pitfalls of returning `this` and enables setting private methods and/or performing complex logic.

Comment: @Snowman Like I said, P.SE *might* be a place, I didn't recommend it. And closing a question here to open somewhere else isn't cross-posting.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you really need fluent methods, because you can simply use object initializer this way:

```
var person = new Person { Name= "Bob", Age= 30 };
```

But in case that you need fluent methods, for example for making multiple overloads for assign a value to a property, for example set a color using int, string or color, here is an option:

**Base builder class:**

```
public class Builder<T, TBuilder>
    where T: new()
    where TBuilder : Builder<T, TBuilder>, new()
{
    protected T model;
    protected Builder()
    {
        model = new T();
    }
    public static TBuilder New()
    {
        return new TBuilder();
    }
    public T Get()
    {
        return model;
    }
}
```

**Person Class:**

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**Person Builder Class:**

```
public class PersonBuilder:Builder<Person, PersonBuilder>
{
    public PersonBuilder():base()
    {
    }
    public PersonBuilder Name(string name)
    {
        model.Name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public PersonBuilder Age(int age)
    {
        model.Age = age;
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var p = PersonBuilder.New().Name("Bob").Age(30).Get();
```

Comment: While I definitely like the builder pattern, in my particular use case it would seem to inhibit later fluent modifications to `bob`.  For example, I'd like to be able to perform `bob.PutACatOnHisHeadJustToScrewWithHim()` later on.

Comment: @ChemicalEngineer And why not using object initializers?

Comment: I'd have two objections to object initializers: (1) use limited to construction; (2) can't perform transmutations repeatedly or in specific orders (this is for a math program).  Honesty fluent methods work great; I'm just curious if there's an easy naming convention to make them even easier to read.

Comment: Tangential question:  Would object initializers have had any benefits over the named-optional-argument approach shown in the question?  Or are object initializers basically a specific subset of named optional arguments?

Comment: @ChemicalEngineer Suppose you have a class with 20 properties that **may** need to be set in constructor. How many constructor you will create for that class? Or do you really want to create a method with 20 parameters?

Comment: @ChemicalEngineer as another benefit for using such builder pattern, using a builder you even can control sequence of calls and only allow some valid sequence of calls using some interfaces And by the way, you are not limited to properties only, you can call some methods as well.